# Form formatting - center form and align its fields to the left

Tags: css, forms

I am trying to center a form, and to align to the left some fields inside of it. Any time I align them to the left- they are not in the center of the webpage, and anytime I center the form, they are not aligned to the left anymore. 
I have checkbox fields. How should I go about this? div? table? other?

Here's the jsFiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/lucyw/FN5BH/13/

Thanks!

Comment: Please create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for us to work with.

Comment: Okay - updated, check it out!

Comment: [Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/FN5BH/21/). Basically, make sure that your elements you want to center have a width less than 100% (I declared it 400px). Then use `margin: 0 auto;` to center them.

Answer (score 3):

I've provided below a pretty standard way of achieving your desired end result:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <label>foo</label>
    <input type="text" name="foo"/>
    <label>fooo</label>
    <input type="text" name="fooo"/>
    <label>foooo</label>
    <input type="text" name="foooo"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container   { width:300px; background-color:#222; overflow:hidden;
               padding:10px; }
form         { color:#FEFEFE; width:250px; margin:0 auto;
               background-color:#F62; }
label, input { float:left; }
label        { clear:left; display:block; width:60px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JQttx/3/